# DropDownList only selecting the initial value not picking the selected value

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

i have a detailview on my aspx page. and by using templates i placed 3 dropdownlist in it. 1 dropdownlist has postback event, and other 2's doesn't. workflow is that the 3rd dropdownlist values are loaded when 1st dropdownlist value is selected. (uptill that works fine). BUT the problem arrises when the form is submitted on the initial value is selected from the 3rd dropdownlist every time. and if i use IsPostBack in the page load event than i would not be able to load form values as i mentioned earlier 1st dropdownlist when ever will be change 3rd dropdownlist will load the values. please do reply i am stuck on this for 2 or more weeks.

Comment: seems like you are populating ddls at pageload without understanding the postback property of page... seeing your page load event in a minimal form would be much better...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to bind ddl3 in ddl1 databound and selectedindexchanged event not in pageload